# After baking in Evee, shadows/texture don't show up when exported to gltf

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, texture-baking, baking

I recently tried to bake with Evee (not cycles because my laptop configuration is pretty old) anyway, the result came out great but when I exported the model to gltf, the shadows and textures created due to indirect light don't show up.
The exported result is plain and bland. I will attach the images below,

1. How I see it when I bake it.
2. How it looks when I export it to gltf. (Plain model just without baking so I'll only attach the screenshot without bake)

[image]

[image]

I do use an "image texture" node in the shading panel and an extra "UV maps" for the model that is to be baked. Yet I see a "Black image" or "no image" when I go to UV editing mode.

Can anyone please kindly explain where I'm going wrong? I also see some 0 MiB, maybe that's a clue?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Eevee's indirect lighting baking is really only for Eevee. It's not baked into the asset data that you can export. For this, you would need to do an actual baking: [Render Baking — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/baking.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. This gives me more clarity. I'm fairly new to blender. So this means I have to bake the model under "Cycles". Correct?